# Маршрутизация в linux

Tags: linux, администрирование, маршрутизация

Существует некий сервер на centos6 с openvz контейнерами на борту. У сервера есть несколько физических интерфейсов, в том числе bond-интерфейс (eth0 + eth2) с адресацией (192.168.2.191/22), из которой берётся адреса для контейнеров. Проблема в том, что физический хост идёт по сети к своим контейнером не через этот-bond, а через eth1 (192.168.254.1/30) который вообще никак не участвует в этом процессе. В чём может быть проблема? Адресация и таблица маршрутов ниже.

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 19:62:ad:f3:81:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 19:62:ad:f3:81:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.254.1/30 brd 192.168.254.3 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 19:62:ad:f3:81:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 19:62:ad:f3:81:d3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 19:62:ad:f3:81:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.191/22 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global bond0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/void 
8: bond0.101@bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 19:62:ad:f3:81:d1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 77.1.14.155/24 brd 77.1.14.255 scope global bond0.101
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever



#ip r   
192.168.2.152 dev venet0  scope link 
192.168.2.19 dev venet0  scope link 
192.168.2.221 dev venet0  scope link 
192.168.2.8 dev venet0  scope link 
192.168.2.99 dev venet0  scope link 
192.168.1.119 dev venet0  scope link 
77.1.14.11 dev venet0  scope link 
77.1.14.22 dev venet0  scope link 
192.168.3.21 dev venet0  scope link 
192.168.2.38 dev venet0  scope link 
192.168.254.0/30 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.254.1 
77.1.14.0/24 dev bond0.51  proto kernel  scope link  src 77.1.14.155
192.168.0.0/22 dev bond0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.191
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1003 
169.254.0.0/16 dev bond0  scope link  metric 1006 
169.254.0.0/16 dev bond0.51  scope link  metric 1008 
default via 77.1.14.155 dev bond0.51
```

Comment: *идёт по сети к своим контейнером* - про какие именно адреса речь? для части ip-адресов из этого диапазона у вас в основной таблице маршрутизации указаны маршруты через venet0. // p.s. 1. таблиц маршрутизации вообще-то несколько больше одной. 2. помимо этого есть ещё и rules (`ip rule`). 3. ну ещё и кэш маршрутов существует (см. `ip r get адрес`).

Comment: Речь про любые адреса из 192.168.0.0/22 . venet0 - это то, что создаёт openvz, вопреки всему, `ip r get 192.168.2.152` говорит `192.168.2.152 dev venet0  src 192.168.254.1`. Я не могу понять, почему он в src подставляет адрес eth1 :(

Comment: *создаёт openvz, вопреки всему* - что значит "вопреки всему"? вероятно, что-то в его конфигурации прописано, благодаря чему программа и добавляет "эксклюзивные маршруты". поройтесь в документации - наверняка можно либо отключить создание таких маршрутов, либо хотя бы при создании делать подсказку netfilter-у в виде указания src. // *почему он в src подставляет адрес eth1* - 1. в маршруте не указан адрес src. 2. алгоритм указания src в таком случае можно посмотреть в исходниках, скорее всего подставляется первый попавшийся local-адрес (разумеется, за исключением интерфейсов типа loopback).

Comment: В конфигах ovz явно не указано ничего, что могло бы повлиять на это. А возможно ли добавить новый системный маршрут с большей метрикой или как-либо ещё, чтоб netfilter выбирал его?

Comment: мне кажется, проще самому добавить нужные src. типа: `$ sudo ip r ch 192.168.2.152 dev venet0  scope link src нужный-ip-адрес`. скорее всего, это должно быть легко автоматизируемо с помощью openvz-шной скриптовой обвязки.

Comment: По-идее вообще надо VE_ROUTE_SRC_DEV использовать, но я это ещё пока не тестил, да и это глобальная настройка, нельзя просто так взять и перезапустить openvz для её применения на тех машинах. Надо какой-то на время костыль вбить, вот я и подумал, мб какой-то маршрут глобальный объявить, или rule написать как-то...

Comment: ну вот вам костыль: `$ ip r sh dev venet0 | grep -v ' src ' | grep '^192\.168' | while read r; do sudo ip r ch $r src 192.168.2.191; done`. запускайте после создания очередного контейнера.

Comment: А вариант [типа такого](https://wiki.openvz.org/Source_based_routing) работать не будет? Я попробовал сделать то же самое, но в `ip r get` src не изменился. Может я что-то не то делаю :(

Comment: вы для начала посмотрите, изменились ли записи в таблице маршрутизации. а get берёт информацию из кэша маршрутов.